# What do you call this input, terminal device?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I was trying to find a word, it's not a terminal, it's not a keyboard, it's an input device with an interface built in. I am trying to find the word. I am specifically talking about the part that allows you to input commands, or whatever the buttons are supposed to do, while I also am wondering what might be the word for the whole actual thing.

Comment: It looks like a control panel to control the flow of aircraft at an airport.  One of the labels below says "runway occupied" and another has the word "airfield".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its broadest sense, it's a [console](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/console) - scroll down to the definition as a noun, not the verb.  Possibly could also be termed a control panel or instrument panel, but I think console is the best description.

> a surface or device with controls for electronic equipment, a vehicle, etc.:
> A sound engineer's console looks as complicated as the cockpit of a jet aircraft.

This is similar to the name for a small hand-held device used for gaming, but pre-dates it.

Also note the emphasis changes between the verb to cons**ole** and the noun, **con**sole.

Answer (score 3):

Control Panel is a thing with buttons or numbers that allow you to send signals to the device and control its behavior.

> [Control panel from Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/control-panel)

**the part of a machine or system that contains its controls:**

- Type your code into the control panel to set the burglar alarm.
- You can use the printer's control panel to select the ink color.